# Vue Cli 3 - Include js file in dist when compile web component

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli-3

I’m working on a project created with Vue Cli 3 and I’ve been working with Vue web components.

I need to create a loader file (called loader.js) that will require different libraries.

```
require(‘.node_modules/…/…/library.js’);
require(‘.node_modules/…/…/script.js’);
```

I use this command to compile the web component:

```
vue-cli-service build --target wc --name widget ./src/components/widget.vue
```

What I need at this point it that when build the web component, webpack also process the loader.js file and bundle all the `require` inside the dist folder.

I’m new working with webpack and I don’t know how can I resolve this. I’ve tried to use the CopyWebpackPlugin but it only copied the loader.js file and does’nt include the require files.

```
module.exports = {
plugins: [
  new CopyWebpackPlugin(
    [
      {
        from: 'src/loader.js',
        to: '.',
      },
    ],
  ),
],
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: If `src/loader.js` isn't referenced anywhere in your component, it won't be bundled. Remove the `CopyWebpackPlugin` config, and import `src/loader.js` from your component file.

Comment: Hi @sergimbo, just wondering if you we're able to solve this problem? I'm also trying to implement this.

Comment: I'm also looking for a solution, I encounter this issue when target is a library

Comment: Just in case this answer is helpful to someone after this time, I found a workaround to this problem. I created a "wrapper" script where I copied manually the `loader.js`file and then executed the "vue-cli-service build ..." command.

Answer (score 3):

If it's a static js file, you can add it into the public folder

> #### The `public` Folder
>
> Any static assets placed in the `public` folder will simply be copied and not go through webpack. You need to reference them using absolute paths.

src: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-public-folder

If it is and/or has dependencies, then using import in your main code will include it in the bundle.

Comment: This only works when the target is App. https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html#app I'm using WebComponents target